# Should I consider the warning when converting model to sdf format in ROS Fuerte using gzsdf?

Tags: gazebo-model, sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am converting the .model files in simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds/objects to the sdf format, since I receive a warning when I use the .model files. When I convert the files, I get the same warning as when using them.

```
$ rosrun gazebo gzsdf print desk6.model > desk.sdf
Warning [parser.cc:348] Gazebo SDF has no gazebo element
Warning [parser.cc:255] DEPRECATED GAZEBO MODEL FILE
On July 1st, 2012, this formate will no longer by supported
Convert your files using the gzsdf command line tool
You have been warned!
```

Am I doing the conversion correctly? I couldn't find the documentation for the gzsdf command, so I hope I am using the right filetypes.

Should I worry about this warning? Will the object behave "normally"? Is this warning a bug or meaningful?

Another question, shouldn't there be sdf format files in the simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds/objects folder? Since sdf is the apparently the new chosen format for gazebo? Doesn't the warning mean that the other formats are not to be used anymore?

Shanker

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/495/should-i-consider-the-warning-when-converting-model-to-sdf-format-in-ros-fuerte-using-gzsdf?/) by [Shanker Keshavdas](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/118/shanker-keshavdas/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 25 on 2012-12-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The model files in ROS's simulator_gazebo package are very old. The gzsdf tool is only meant to work with SDF file, which was first introduced in Gazebo 1.0.

Basically, support for file formats prior to gazebo 1.0 are not supported. The gzsdf tool may work, but I can't guarantee it.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2012-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [davetcoleman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134/davetcoleman/) on 2013-01-02**:
Is there a tool for converting URDF -> SDF, at least the parts that can be converted? Doing this manually looks like a painstaking process.

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-01-09**:
The command line tool `gzsdf` should convert for you.